# Split string using 2 criterias in PHP

Tags: php, string, explode

I am using this

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($text));
```

to split $text into an array of lines so i can display like this:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
 echo $line;
}
```

but now i want to test the lenght of each $line and if lenght is over 50 chars i want to split each line in multiple of 50 chars.

How can i do this and keep all lines in the $lines array ?

I need a way to test each line or explode it using explode( wordwrap($line), 50 ); and then re-build the $lines array so i can cycle all lines again.

As I am not a coder I do not know how to insert new lines in the array if one line must be split in several pieces of 50 chars.

Hope you understand my question.
Thanks.

Comment: So, you're exploding your `$text`, then want to print each array index out in chunks of 50 characters?

Comment: Be careful using PHP_EOL - if this file comes from a system with a different eol char than the system you're running the code on, you'll be exploding the wrong thing.

Comment: Hi Marc, is there a better way instead of PHP_EOL ? 
For the second filter i want to split into chunks of 50 characters but then i want to insert this new lines into the $lines array so i can use later, hope you understand my idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what [`chunk_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) is made for:

```
echo chunk_split( $line, 50 );
```

This'll break your `$line` into multiple lines of 50 characters each.

---

**Update** after the OP specified that he wants to split the lines into individual elements in the array:

```
$temp = explode( PHP_EOL, trim($text) );
$lines = array();

foreach ($temp as $line) {
   $lines = array_merge( $lines, str_split($line, 50) );
}
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/eRgm6p

Comment: @Matt - You do realize that I put a link right there in the post!?

Comment: OOPS! Sorry, didn't mean to steal your thunder!

Comment: Many thanks, .. but after i chunk_split the line how can i add this new lines to the $lines array so i can use this array later?

Comment: @PedroP - I didn't realize you wanted to reuse them later. How do you want it? Do you want a multi-dimensional array? Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, it is a one dimension array with all the lines.

First i explode(PHP_EOL, trim($text)); and this will result in for example 15 lines.

Then i want to test each line for the 50 chars and could reult in a final array of 25 lines for example which i want to keep in the $lines array.

Comment: Just a small issue Joseph.. 

Is there any adjustment i can add to your code so the split will be "around 50 char" so that no word would be split ? 

Sorry for not taking this in account..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to do the splitting within your `foreach`, then use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to put the new elements into the place of the old one.

In practice, it would look something like this:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, trim($text));
foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
    if (strlen($line) > 50) {
        $split = str_split($line, 50);
        $lines = array_splice($lines, $i, 1, $split);
    }
}
reset($lines);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Palladium, am also testing this code but for some reason it is not spliting the 50 chars.. will check if i am not doing anything wrong.